# how to plot pie chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following dataframe in R and want to make pie chart out of it

```
berth_day count
Friday    74
Monday    95
Saturday  126
Sunday    114
Thursday  62
Tuesday   85
```

I am doing following in R

```
ggplot(aes(x=berth_day, y=count))+
geom_bar(width =1)
+ coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

But,it gives me following error

```
> ggplot(aes(x=berth_day, y=count))+
+   geom_bar(width =1)
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
>   + coord_polar(theta = "y")
Error in +coord_polar(theta = "y") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

How can I do it in R ?

Comment: just move the second `+` to the end of the previous line

Comment: Where did you provide the `data` i.e. `ggplot(data, aes(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether the OP's data comes from a pipe or forgot to add in the `ggplot` call

```
df1N <- df1 %>% mutate(berth_day = factor(berth_day))

ggplot(df1N,  aes(x=berth_day, y=count, fill = berth_day))+
    geom_bar(width =1, stat = "identity")+ 
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

As @GGamba said in the comments, `geom_bar` is deprecated instead use `geom_col`

```
ggplot(df1N,  aes(x=berth_day, y=count, fill = berth_day))+
    geom_col(width=1)+ 
    coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Comment: `geom_bar(width=1, stat = "identity")` has been 'deprecated' in favor of `geom_col(width=1)`

Comment: @akrun How can I differentiate between days in above chart?

Comment: @Neil I am updating the post, please wait

Comment: @Neil Updated the post

Answer (score 1):

A proper pie is contructed this way:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = 1, y = count, fill = berth_day))+
    geom_col(position = 'stack', 
             show.legend = F) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(berth_day, ': ', count)), 
               position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    theme_void()
```

[image]

data:

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = 'berth_day count
Friday    74
                  Monday    95
                  Saturday  126
                  Sunday    114
                  Thursday  62
                  Tuesday   85', h = T)
```